# Javascript Unicode White Space

Tags: javascript, unicode, replace

I need the replace() to recognize space around the 'I' so it only makes the pronoun 'I' in an inputted string lower case, not every 'I' in a sentence.

```
var1 = var1.replace(/\u0020 I \u0020/g, "i");
```

What am I doing wrong??

EDIT: both

```
var1 = var1.replace(/ I /g, " i ");
```

and

```
var1 = var1.replace(/\bI\b/g, "i");
```

work. Thank you :)

Comment: You may want to consider the _RegExp_ `/\bI\b/g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are replacing the spaces as well. You probably want to keep those.

```
var1 = var1.replace(/ I /g, " i ");
```

Comment: @torazaburo in my case it doesn't need to (thank you tho c: )